# How to make a 40X40 grid of boxes with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to make a 40 X 40 grid of boxes with outlines, and |I want the whole grid to be shown without the need to scroll, by my method the grid outgrows the screen so I have to scroll.

If the screen size is changed the size of individual boxes should change, and I want the grid to fill the entire div its in.

```css
/*this is the container */
.grid-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
}

/*this is the individual box*/
.node {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid #0f0e0e;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    // .... 40 times
    <div class="node"></div>
  </div>
  // ....40 times
  <div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    // .... 40 times
    <div class="node"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a total 30 x 30 grid, I would love to be able to do this with CSS only.

Comment: take a look at flexbox

Comment: Does each grid cell have to be an HTML element? Or could you use SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a grid of 20 x 20 (Stack Overflow doesn't like too much characters in a post and the HTML is big), using `flex` display for both columns and rows.

The `main` element has a limited height and represents the external element that constrains the grid, and the grid takes the maximum size horizontally and vertically from what is available.

```css
main {
  height: 150px;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.node {
  outline: 1px solid #0f0e0e;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are looking for something like this?

```css
.grid {
   margin: 10px; 
}

/* this is the individual box */
.row {
    display: block;
}

.box{
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the html is alot cleaner in react, take a look at this: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/oWWQNa . it's from the react tutorial : https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-1-write-code-in-the-browser

Comment: i want to make something where the boxes size are not fixed rather their layout is fixed as n X n, and all the grid is displayed without need to scroll